# Lock-free fetch_add much slower than mutex?

Tags: c++, mutex, lock-free

My test shows that using lock-free atomic fetch_add is much slower than using mutex. I am running 10 parallel threads adding 1 million to the shared counter each. I am using relaxed memory order. Did I do the atomic wrong?

output from test:

```
fetch_add elapsed time: 4.14048 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 5.37776 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 5.37771 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 5.37791 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 5.37865 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 7.85113 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 7.93542 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 7.96275 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 7.97306 secs
Result from fetch_add:1000000000
Lock elapsed time: 0.214009 secs
Lock elapsed time: 0.418662 secs
Lock elapsed time: 0.633993 secs
Lock elapsed time: 0.836704 secs
Lock elapsed time: 1.04225 secs
Lock elapsed time: 1.24322 secs
Lock elapsed time: 1.44627 secs
Lock elapsed time: 1.64898 secs
Lock elapsed time: 1.8539 secs
Lock elapsed time: 2.05816 secs
Result from lock:1000000000
```

Testing code:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>       /* time */
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono> 

const int BILLION = 1000000000L;
std::mutex my_mutex;
int global_val = 0;
std::atomic<unsigned long> global_a_val(0);

void LockFree(int length) {
  struct timespec start, end;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    global_a_val.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

  auto diff = BILLION * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
  std::cout<<"fetch_add elapsed time: "<< (double)diff/BILLION <<" secs\n";
}

void Lock(int length) {
  struct timespec start, end;

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
  {
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> my_lock(my_mutex);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      auto pre = ++global_val;
    }
  }
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

  auto diff = BILLION * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
  std::cout<<"Lock elapsed time: "<< (double)diff/BILLION <<" secs\n";
}

int main() {
  const int thread_count = 10;
  const int count = 100000000;
  std::thread t[thread_count];
  for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {
    t[i] = std::thread(LockFree, count);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {
    t[i].join();
  }
  std::cout<<"Result from fetch_add:"<<global_a_val<<"\n";
  
  std::thread t2[thread_count];
  for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {
    t2[i] = std::thread(Lock, count);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {
    t2[i].join();
  }
  std::cout<<"Result from lock:"<<global_val<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Why did you expect the different result? In one case you do an atomic operation per loop iteration, in another case you lock the mutex once per thread. It's not surprising that 10 billion atomic adds shared by 10 threads are slower than, essentially, 10 billion non atomic adds in one thread. Btw, how many cores does your PC have?

Answer (score 8):

It is obvious that it will be slower because you lock mutex only **once**. Here in this code:

```
  {
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> my_lock(my_mutex);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      auto pre = ++global_val;
    }
  }
```

You only lock mutex once and then you use loop to normally add values, but in `fetch_add` atomic add happens every time. It is obvious that a normal add is quicker than atomic add and this comparison is not correct. If you want to compare them correctly, you need a code like this:

```
  {   
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> my_lock(my_mutex);
      auto pre = ++global_val;
    }
  }
```

To compare, your code on my vm gives following times:

```
fetch_add elapsed time: 11.5873 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.0809 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.2435 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.5315 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.6408 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.7246 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.8112 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.813 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.8739 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.9213 secs
Result from fetch_add:1000000000
Lock elapsed time: 0.259349 secs
Lock elapsed time: 0.51883 secs
Lock elapsed time: 0.779507 secs
Lock elapsed time: 1.03916 secs
Lock elapsed time: 1.3016 secs
Lock elapsed time: 1.56413 secs
Lock elapsed time: 1.82421 secs
Lock elapsed time: 2.08337 secs
Lock elapsed time: 2.34295 secs
Lock elapsed time: 2.60248 secs
Result from lock:1000000000
```

but after the change that I mentioned, results will be like this:

```
fetch_add elapsed time: 11.4242 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 11.9451 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 11.9901 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.0678 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.1317 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.505 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.5591 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.7394 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.8966 secs
fetch_add elapsed time: 12.9199 secs
Result from fetch_add:1000000000
Lock elapsed time: 70.9624 secs
Lock elapsed time: 70.9993 secs
Lock elapsed time: 71.0727 secs
Lock elapsed time: 71.0932 secs
Lock elapsed time: 71.0966 secs
Lock elapsed time: 71.1221 secs
Lock elapsed time: 71.143 secs
Lock elapsed time: 71.1462 secs
Lock elapsed time: 71.158 secs
Lock elapsed time: 71.1588 secs
Result from lock:1000000000
```

Comment: thanks. My bad... didn't realize. now it is more like it.